# Java fibonacci - find user input from array

Tags: java, fibonacci

Couple issues I am having with my fibonacci code. If I want to find the location of number 5 in the array (input), the system says its location is 5, but it should say 6? Also, if I enter a number that is not in the array, the system says it is found in location 20 (example input 200). System should say it is "not found"

```
    int totalFibos=20;
    int fibs[] = new int[totalFibos];

    int a=0;
    int b=1;
    int fib=0;
    fibs[0]=0;

    fibs[1]=1;

    int fibCounter=2;
    while(fibCounter<totalFibos)
    {
        fib=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=fib;
        fibs[fibCounter]=fib;
        fibCounter++;
    }
    System.out.println("\n\nThe first "+ totalFibos + " fibonacci numbers are: ");
    int i=0;

    while(i<totalFibos)
    {
        System.out.print(fibs[i]+" ");
        i=i+1;
    }
    System.out.println();
    int userInput=0;
    i=0;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    int found=0;
    while(userInput!=-1)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number to search,(enter -1 to end the search): ");
        userInput= sc.nextInt();

        while (i<totalFibos)
        {
            if(userInput==fibs[i])
            {
                found=1;
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if(found==1)
            System.out.println("The number: " + userInput + " is found at location: "+ i++);
                    else if (found==0)
                            System.out.println("The number: "+ userInput + " is not found");
            }

                    if(userInput==-1)
            System.out.println("\nThanks");
            }



    }
```

Comment: Probably it says 5 instead of 6 because in java, array indices are : `0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , ...`

Comment: 0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 etc... should be in the array (if I did it correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your refactored code :

```
int totalFibos=20;
int fibs[] = new int[totalFibos];

int a=0;
int b=1;
int fib=0;
fibs[0]=0;

fibs[1]=1;

int fibCounter=2;
while(fibCounter<totalFibos)
{
    fib=a+b;
    a=b;
    b=fib;
    fibs[fibCounter]=fib;
    fibCounter++;
}
System.out.println("\n\nThe first "+ totalFibos + " fibonacci numbers are: ");
int i=0;

while(i<totalFibos)
{
    System.out.print(fibs[i]+" ");
    i=i+1;
}
System.out.println();
int userInput=0;
i=0;
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
int found=0;
while(userInput!=-1)
{
    System.out.println("Enter a number to search,(enter -1 to end the search): "); //Shouldnt this be println ?
    userInput= sc.nextInt();
    i=0; //Reset it, else the second search would fail
    found=0; //Reset it, else the second search would fail
    while (i<totalFibos)
    {
        if(userInput==fibs[i]);
        {
            found=1;
            break;
        }
        i++; //Change state of i

    }
    if (found==1) { //Wheres your bracket ?
       System.out.println("The number: " + userInput + " is found at location: "+ Integer.toString(i+1)); //Just to be sure...
    }
    else if (found==0) {
       System.out.println("The number: "+ userInput + " is not found");
    }
 }
    if(userInput==-1)
        System.out.println("\nThanks");
    }
```

Hope it works and helps you !

Comment: @buliukko : Cheat-Solution : Just change i+1 to i+2 :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have ";" sign after if statement in

```
    if(userInput==fibs[i]);
    {
        found=1;
        break;
    }
```

That is why it expression in {} is always executed. 
Remove the ";" and add i++; somewhere inside the while loop for this to work.

Update:
Also reset your counter and result after every input. This should be the first thing inside your while loop:

```
    found = 0;
    i = 0;
```

Comment: ups! Yeah I had that one there but I guess I deleted it when I was trying to fix the issues... Anyway, still the same problems that I mentioned in the topic

Comment: Reset your result and counter after every input. I updated the answer.